# iOS Text Input Traits and How to Stop Quicktype aka Predictive Text From Adding a Space?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, interface-builder, quicktype

In iOS 11 (11.0.3 to be exact), a space gets added when a person taps on the word offered by QuickType aka Predictive Text.

You can see the "Michael" being offered:
[image: Michael offered]

Here it shows the space character that was inserted after the Michael was tapped (Xs added just to show the space):
[image]

My Interface Builder settings on the field look like the following: 
[image: Text Input Traits of Given Name]

**Using Text Input Traits only, how do I keep the space from getting added when a word is selected using QuickType aka Predictive Text?** I tried setting `UITextSmartInsertDeleteType` to no and that works for paste. However, it does not work for QuickType / Predictive Text.

Here is the [smartInsertDeleteType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/2865828-smartinsertdeletetype) documentation. In the Apple forums, I only found this related conversation: [Re: Predictive Text Bug?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/271330)

Since we have validation on the fields that we want to use QuickType on (email addresses, phone numbers, and so on), it's not good enough to just trim off the space after the fact.

I already know about `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` and hope I don't have to deal with it there.

Comment: What did you end up figuring out? I'm running into this same issue. Unfortunately, the Apple Forums link is a dead thread as well.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I'm having the same problem...Can't find any solution for this in internet